# RegEx with spaces and delimiters

Tags: sql, regex, google-bigquery

I have a two columns with the following data:

Column 1: BIG123 - Telecommunications (John Barrot)

Column 2: 7 Congressional 1 - Toward

The data format is the same with spaces and the "-" as the delimiter for each column, but the organization, names, and beginning code can be longer or shorter than what you see here(instead of Telecommunications it can be CEO or instead of John Barrott it can be Guy Rodriguez, etc).  I need to extract the following:

(Column names are in bold)

**Organization**     Telecommunications

**Supervisor** John Barrot

**Profile**
Congressional 1 - Toward

I have been using the following cheat sheet but I am still having issues extracting:  https://cheatography.com/davechild/cheat-sheets/regular-expressions/

I have tried regex_extract(column1, [A-Z][a-z]) and I only get the first two letters of column 1 after the "-".

Any help would be great.

Thanks,

DW

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With your example try the following

```
with sample_data as (
    select 'BIG123 - Telecommunications (John Barrot)' AS COLUMN_1, '7 Congressional 1 - Toward' as COLUMN_2
)
select regexp_extract(COLUMN_1, r'.+-\s(\S+)') as Organization
    , regexp_extract(COLUMN_1, r'.+\((.+\w)') as Supervisor
    , regexp_extract(COLUMN_2, r'\d+\s(.+)') as Profile
from sample_data
```

Comment: Thanks for the break down Daniel.  Do you have any recommendations on how to learn the correct syntax for the regex function?  I've looked and I don't see any that explain the format.

Comment: I typically use regex101 figure out the regex pattern, it gives a breakdown of the match and why, the components of the pattern, and has searchable reference library on the screen.  Here is an example of the pattern for profile in the above example: https://regex101.com/r/FdUXqN/1  additionally you can find documentation on the BigQuery regext extract function here: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/string_functions#regexp_extract